# questionable computation in a paper by Lele and Allen

Tags: fisher-information

I'm reading "On Using Expert Opinion in Ecological Analyses: a Frequentist Approach" by S.R. Lele and Kristie Allen.  In that paper (http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~slele/publications/LeleAllen06.pdf), a certain score function arises (on page 7):

$$f = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{j = 1}^n (O_j - \mu) + \frac{\eta}{1 + \eta^2\sigma^2}\sum_{j = n + 1}^N (E_j - \eta \mu) $$

(The $\sigma^2$ in the first term is missing in the paper but I'm pretty sure that's a mistake.)  Here, $\sigma$ and $\eta$ are *known* parameters, $O_j$ and $E_j$ are random variables with normal distributions $O_j \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $E_j \sim N(\eta \mu, 1 + \eta^2 \sigma^2)$.  We are trying to compute the Fisher information (for $\mu$) from the above score.  One way to do this is by computing $-E[\partial_\mu f]$.  Differentiating $f$ with respect to $\mu$ gives

$$ \partial_\mu f = -\frac{n}{\sigma^2} - \frac{(N - n)\eta^2}{1 + \eta^2\sigma^2}, $$
whence the Fisher information is $\frac{n}{\sigma^2} + \frac{(N - n)\eta^2}{1 + \eta^2\sigma^2}$.

The formula given in the paper for the Fisher information is
$$ \frac{\left(n + \frac{(N - n)\eta^2}{1 + \eta^2\sigma^2}\right)^2}{n\sigma^2 + \frac{(N - n)\eta^2}{1 + \eta^2\sigma^2}} $$
and this is not equivalent to the formula I derived.

Did I make a computational (or theoretical?) mistake?  If my computation is correct then it invalidates a claim in the paper (that the Fisher information is not always greater than $\frac{n}{\sigma^2}$).

Comment: Please provide a full reference and/or stable URL. Readers should not have to Google to find a reference, especially when it is central to a question.